# How do you configure Firefox to start with a new profile every time?

Tags: firefox, profile

Seems like a pretty common use case for developers, but there is no setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove the profile, then script a startup script that removes the profile directory.  I haven't seen any need to do this as a developer.  Setting firefox to flush cookies, history, and cache on exit may be more common, and is supported.

Much of what you may want may be covered by the Web Developer plug-in.  It will flush cookeis, cache, etc.  Usually, you won't even need to restart.

Answer (score 0):

Start Firefox by running

```
firefox.exe -p
```

Create new profile and delete old one.

Here is a more detailed description (official website)
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles